# is there a way to tag people to a slack slash command

Tags: slack

So what I want to do is start a `/zoom` meeting command but I also want to tag my team at the same time so that they get the notification on Slack that we are on a Zoom meeting.

Answer (score 0):

The '/Zoom' command does not have an option to tag a user,

but the ideal way to do that would be to open a DM/Multi-Person DM conversation of all the participants and then use the slash command.